# How to tunnel for MySQL using vmc in cloudfoundry?

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry

I'm just starting out with CloudFoundry and I understand that the only way to be able to execute a sql dump against a db is to

1. Create MySQL service
2. Bind Service
3. Tunnel to the service
   But I'm not getting any luck on the last part. I followed the directions from [cloud foundry forum discussion](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21311716-how-can-i-work-with-mysql-service)

I select option *1. None* But I just don't know how run 
mysql --protocol=TCP --host=localhost --port=10000 --user=ub2sCBQ0mGsVZ --password=pRXana7vEOX0C df83386088ffc4f8d8cf288791d22fb99 < sample.sql

from command line (Windows) or from SQLyog.

The other part of the question is of course once I am able to create the database and the tables and insert data into them. How does my webapp need to connect to the database? 
On one hand I think I know the answer [as described here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services/mysql/mysql.html)
But I can't believe that this is the only way. This is damn difficult with Spring because I would have to read the env in before the entire Spring/Hibernate machinery starts creating the needed beans. Is there an example of less complex way to do this ?

Comment: Based on Dan's suggestion I used the workbench as opposed to command line or SQLyog and the first part has been put to rest. It works, just start the tunnel (i.e. 1.none) and then create a connection on localhost. Don't forget to specify the correct port which in this case is 10000 not 3306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Windows I would suggest using MySQL workbench to connect using the credentials provided when opening the tunnel using VMC. You can download it from the MySQL website here;

https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

When deploying a Spring application that uses a MySQL service you can have it automatically configure the database connection in your app. See the following page for details;

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html#determining-whether-your-application-can-be-auto-configured

Comment: Thanks Dan, I guess it was just my SQL client and lack of confidence that things would auto-magically work. Cloudfoundry rocks.

Comment: NP Alex, It does indeed rock!